# In canada, my 3-year degree is a bachelor or an associated?

Tags: masters, degree, bachelor, canada, brazil

I'm taking a 3-year college in software development. Where I live (Brazil) it's not considered a Bachelor (4 years, at least). I don't know where my course fits in Canada's classification. It's not an Associate (2 years) nor a Bachelor (4 years). What's the equivalent of my degree in Canada? (I can't apply for equivalence programs. I haven't finished my college yet).
Am I able to apply for a master in Canada with my 3-year college?

Comment: Canada is very large and province have different policies. In Québec, 3-year is the usual length of a bachelor, at the exception of "professional" bachelors (teaching, engineering...). Where do you want to apply?

Comment: @Emilie I'm very interested in Ontario, but is not the only, I would live anywhere in Canada as long as the province accepts only my english as primary language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your degree should not be qualified as an associated. But it does not give an immediate answer on your chances of being admitted (or being qualified to enter) to the particular M.Sc. program.

The answer will depend on the regulations of the particular university (and maybe even the Faculty/Department) you are applying to and what is actually written on your transcript/diploma.

Particular things that are of the importance:

- What is the official title of your degree (on your diploma) and how is it translated into English?
- Total # credit hours that you have taken (3-year degrees can be very different)
- The particular set of courses you've taken towards your degree and how they are related towards the expectations of the M.Sc. program you are applying to.
- If you are applying for a research-based program if your potential advisor is willing to admit you.
- If the intended sources of funding (if you intend to use any) have some stricter requirements than general admission ones.

You would certainly be a good candidate for so-called pre-M.Sc. program, in which for one or two terms you would take some more courses relevant to your degree - and, maybe, even start some research projects.

Also, the admission committee might conditionally admit you to the M.Sc. program with the requirement to take an extra # credit hours.

There are certainly cases when a 3-year degree holder goes for an M.Sc. program directly; however, the general expectation (from my understanding of at least Univ. of Manitoba - no official affiliation, just a former student) for software engineering is that you hold a 4-year degree (B.Sc. or even Honours).